# SelectDialog Only returns the first 20 items

Tags: select, modal-dialog, sapui5

I have this Fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
 <SelectDialog  title="{i18n>titreVoiture}" search="ChercherVoiture" 
 confirm="fermerdialog"
 cancel="fermerdialog" items="{VoitureModel>/GrosVoitures}">
 <StandardListItem title="{VoitureModel>NomVoiture}" type="Active"/>
 </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I am handling the selection of items.  I put the selected items in an array and then when I click to open the dialog, I loop on the items and set the items manually with `setSelected()` if it exists in the array  the problem is when I want to retrieve the items using  `this._valueHelpDialog.getItems()`.

It only returns the first 20 items, and I checked the modal and in the list it displays all the items, so I wonder why `getitems()` doesn't return all items.

Comment: Can you share your complete code of controller part.

Answer (score 0):

If your entity set in gateway have 1 million records, UI5 will not lot all of them - assuming you are using an oData Model.

When your model is an ODataModel, lists by default consume the entity sets using query parameters $top and $skip. Also, by default Lists get records by blocks of 20.

As you called method "getItems" - you are getting the items in your list, not data from your model.

It's possible to use the method read of class ODataModel to read your entity set without binding it to a control however I believe reading a pottentially large data set inside you app is not ideal.

If would be helpful to share what you are trying to achieve apart from sharing your code.

Comment: thank you for answering  ok so i put the selected items in an array and then when i click to open the dialog i loop on the items and (set the items manually with setSelected() if it exists in the array  )

Comment: Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve